# Azure DevOps not to trigger release automatically

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a pipeline set up with continuous integration and two releases.  Both releases are triggered on commit. I only want to trigger one of them.  How do I stop the other one from triggering automatically?

Comment: You can disable CI for the release pipeline that you do not want to get triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean you have 2 release pipelines, or 2 release stages.

Either way, you can use filters to achieve what you need. For release pipelines, you can add a branch filter on the build artifact. For release stages you can add an artifact filter on each stage.

The filters work by letting you specify branches and or tags. You could set it up that builds made from branch A will always trigger release pipeline A or release stage A.

You could also specify tags. These tags are build tags, not to be confused with git tags. When you manually run a build pipeline you can add a tag, or you can programmatically add it during the build pipeline in the yaml.

You could then set it up that certain tags need to be present on builds for certain release pipelines or stages to be triggered.